# How to inject css styles from file to WebComponent

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, web-component

I am wondering is it possible to inject `.css` styles imported from file to WebComponent (If yes then please tell me how can I achieve this). I used Webpack `style-loader` to load `.css` styles inside `.js` a file but then I do not know how (or is it possible) to inject those styles into WebComponent the template.

> I know that I can export styles from `.js` file declared in template string but it is not a solution which I am looking for.

I created a repository with simple example which you can find here: [inject-css-from-file](https://github.com/kaczor6418/inject-css-from-file). I also include those files here:

**index.html :**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
</head>
<body>
    <kk-app></kk-app>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.js :**

```js
import style from "./index.css";

const template = `
<style>${style}</style>
<div>
    <p>Example component</p>
</div>
`;

export class App extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
        this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = template;
    }
}
customElements.define('kk-app', App);
```

**index.css :**

```
p {
    color: red;
}
```

**webpack.config.js :**

```js
const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: './index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js'],
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    plugins: [
        new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'),
            filename: 'index.html',
        }),
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution for that was to remove `style-loader` from `webpack.config.js`. Rule for `.css` file should look like that:

```js
rules: [
    {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['css-loader'],
    },
],
```

I do not know why but `style-loader` changed this `.css` styles into an object.

> **P.S.** If you are using `MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader` it will cause same problem

Comment: Thanks..  Your question and answer saved my day!